# Regex to exclude a string from anywhere, but match another expression

Tags: regex, impala, regex-negation

I'm quite new to regex. Tried to look at other questions but still can't workout how to resolve my scenario. I want to match string that starts with "AB" but not ABC,or string contains DE but not DEF. For example sDEN23, DET or DE should be matches, AB3 should be matches. I've tried the below so far but it doesn't work as expected. Could someone please help? Many thanks.

Edited: How can this be achieved without using lookahead and lookbehind, as these are not support by Impala?

```
 .*AB?[^C].*|.*DE?[^DEF]
```

Comment: Do you want to require BOTH?  So, AB "and" DE, or is it "or"?

Comment: What if the input is "aaaDEaaaDEFaaa". Should it be accepted because of the first DE, or should it be rejected because of the second DEF? What if the input is "ABaaaDEFaaa". Should it be accepted because of the first AB, or should it be rejected because of the second DEF? What if the input is "ABCaaaDEaaa". Should it be rejected because of the first ABC, or should it be accepted because of the DE?

Comment: Should `ABCDE` match, because it contains `DE` (despite starting with `ABC`)? Or is starting with `ABC` never a match, despite containing `DE`. Similarly, is `ABDEF` a match because it starts with `AB` (and not `ABC`) despite containing `DEF`?

Comment: To match `AB` and either end or next character is not `C` one would use: [`AB(?:[^C]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Txp7PK/1) (remove `?:` if *non-capture groups* are not supported by impala regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern to avoid matches followed by certain characters:

```
^(?:AB(?!C)|(?!.*DEF).*DE).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/DH1WTf/3

EDIT: Since you've updated the question by replacing the `python` tag with `impala`, whose regex engine does not support lookarounds, you can instead use multiple `LIKE` operators to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (col LIKE 'AB%' OR col LIKE '%DE%') AND NOT (col LIKE 'ABC%' OR col LIKE '%DEF%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
(AB)([^C^\n\r])+|(DE)([^F^\n\r])+
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't show DE as a match.

Comment: @user3735871 https://regex101.com/r/wqXWU0/1 its working????

Comment: I mean if I type DE only on its own, it doesn't show as a match

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead for your restrictions, and a match for either of your targets:

```
^(?!ABC|DEF)(AB|DE).*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/nygimVrwQhn5mN).

Comment: This will not match `sDEN23`, since the OP wants to match strings that "contains `DE`", not just starts with `DE`.